# Getting all events attended by friends on Facebook through FQL

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-events

I try to get a list of all events attended by all friends on facebook. Here is the query:

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time, eid FROM event 
WHERE eid IN (
       SELECT eid FROM event_member 
       WHERE (uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())  OR uid = me())
   )
AND start_time > now()
```

Although I can see my friends attending certain events on [facebook.com/events/list](https://www.facebook.com/events/list), the result of the FQL query is an emtpy array.

Does anyone have an idea why?

Thanks.

**Update:**

I've added the user_events and friends_events permissions as suggested in the first answer, but the returned list is still empty.

Comment: I've tried that, but I get { "error": "Request failed" } from the Graph Explorer. First, I've tried without permissions and I got empty data. Then, I scope user_events and friends_events permissions and I'm still getting "request failed" error. I also added LIMIT 20 but nothing. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is ok.

- Just add `LIMIT 20` for example if your query takes a took long time,
- Add the `user_events` and `friends_events` [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/).

Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event_member

**Update:**

Permissions should be set in the cloud & then requested on login from your client. Here is the login:

```
FB.login(callback, {scope: 'user_events,friends_events'});
```

Comment: I have set these permissions (in the User & Friend Permissions field), but still no-joy. I can see there are future events attended by my friends, but these are not returned as a result from the query. :(

Comment: I didn't request the permissions from the client app. Updated your post and marked it as an answer. Thanks.